# How to Subplots Mesh3D with Plotly Python

Tags: python, plotly, mesh, subplot

I thought to draw a huge variety of cubes,
so referenced the following link:

SAMPLE1: https://plotly.com/python/3d-mesh/#mesh-cube
SAMPLE2: https://plotly.com/python/3d-subplots/#3d-surface-subplots
API: https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.subplots.make_subplots.html

and a little bit altered to get x,y,z position parameters from json.

Then wrote code below. why not work and thanks in advance.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
import math
import os
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


# SET CONFIG OF FIGURE
def config(r,c):
    for idx, (id,x,y,z) in enumerate(zip(_i, _x, _y, _z)):

        # DRAW A CUBE
        chunk = go.Figure(data=[
            go.Mesh3d(
                x=[0.0, 0.0, x, x, 0.0, 0.0, x, x],
                y=[0.0, y, y, 0.0, 0.0, y, y, 0.0],
                z=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, z, z, z, z],
                intensity = np.linspace(0, 1, 8, endpoint=True),
                intensitymode = 'cell',
                i = [7, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 0, 3, 2],
                j = [3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 6, 3],
                k = [0, 7, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 1, 5, 5, 7, 6],
                showscale=False
            )])
        # APPEND THE CUBE
        fig.add_trace(chunk, row=r, col=c) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # LOAD DATA
    in1 = "data.json"
    with open(in1, mode='r', encoding='utf-8_sig') as f:
        _df = json.load(f)
    df = pd.DataFrame(_df)

    # READ ID,X,Y,Z FROM DATAFRAME
    _i = df.iloc[:, 0]
    _x = df.iloc[:, 2]
    _y = df.iloc[:, 3]
    _z = df.iloc[:, 4]

    specs = []

    # SET SUBPLOT POSITION CLOSEST TO SQUARE
    rows = round(len(_i) **(1/2))  
    cols = rows + math.ceil((len(_i)%rows)/rows)
    for r in range(rows):
        _ = []
        for c in range(cols):
            _ += [{'type': 'mesh3d'}]
        specs += [_]
    fig = make_subplots(rows=rows, cols=cols,specs=specs)

    for r in range(rows):
        for c in range(cols):
            config(r,c)

    #  DRAW ALL CUBES
    fig.show()
```

Error :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ff653a5829ea> in <module>
     17 for r in range(rows):
     18     for c in range(cols):
---> 19         config(r,c)
     20 fig.show()

<ipython-input-6-30b9398571d7> in config(r, c)
     23         )
     24 
---> 25         fig.add_trace(chunk, row=r, col=c)

~/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in add_trace(self, trace, row, col, secondary_y, exclude_empty_subplots)
   2102             cols=[col] if col is not None else None,
   2103             secondary_ys=[secondary_y] if secondary_y is not None else None,
-> 2104             exclude_empty_subplots=exclude_empty_subplots,
   2105         )
   2106 

~/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py in add_traces(self, data, rows, cols, secondary_ys, exclude_empty_subplots)
   2181 
   2182         # Validate traces
-> 2183         data = self._data_validator.validate_coerce(data)
   2184 
   2185         # Set trace indexes

~/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_plotly_utils/basevalidators.py in validate_coerce(self, v, skip_invalid, _validate)
   2675 
   2676             if invalid_els:
-> 2677                 self.raise_invalid_elements(invalid_els)
   2678 
   2679             v = to_scalar_or_list(res)

~/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/versions/3.7.5/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_plotly_utils/basevalidators.py in raise_invalid_elements(self, invalid_els)
    300                     pname=self.parent_name,
    301                     invalid=invalid_els[:10],
--> 302                     valid_clr_desc=self.description(),
    303                 )
    304             )

ValueError: 
    Invalid element(s) received for the 'data' property of 
        Invalid elements include: [Figure({
    'data': [{'i': [7, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 0, 3, 2],
              'intensity': array([0.        , 0.14285714, 0.28571429, 0.42857143, 0.57142857, 0.71428571,
                                  0.85714286, 1.        ]),
              'intensitymode': 'cell',
              'j': [3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 6, 3],
              'k': [0, 7, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 1, 5, 5, 7, 6],
              'showscale': False,
              'type': 'mesh3d',
              'x': [0.0, 0.0, 0.7, 0.7, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7, 0.7],
              'y': [0.0, 1.11, 1.11, 0.0, 0.0, 1.11, 1.11, 0.0],
              'z': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65, 0.65]}],
    'layout': {'height': 400, 'template': '...', 'title': {'text': 'NO.3488', 'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.55}, 'width': 400}
})]

    The 'data' property is a tuple of trace instances
    that may be specified as:
      - A list or tuple of trace instances
        (e.g. [Scatter(...), Bar(...)])
      - A single trace instance
        (e.g. Scatter(...), Bar(...), etc.)
      - A list or tuple of dicts of string/value properties where:
        - The 'type' property specifies the trace type
            One of: ['area', 'bar', 'barpolar', 'box',
                     'candlestick', 'carpet', 'choropleth',
                     'choroplethmapbox', 'cone', 'contour',
                     'contourcarpet', 'densitymapbox', 'funnel',
                     'funnelarea', 'heatmap', 'heatmapgl',
                     'histogram', 'histogram2d',
                     'histogram2dcontour', 'image', 'indicator',
                     'isosurface', 'mesh3d', 'ohlc', 'parcats',
                     'parcoords', 'pie', 'pointcloud', 'sankey',
                     'scatter', 'scatter3d', 'scattercarpet',
                     'scattergeo', 'scattergl', 'scattermapbox',
                     'scatterpolar', 'scatterpolargl',
                     'scatterternary', 'splom', 'streamtube',
                     'sunburst', 'surface', 'table', 'treemap',
                     'violin', 'volume', 'waterfall']

        - All remaining properties are passed to the constructor of
          the specified trace type

        (e.g. [{'type': 'scatter', ...}, {'type': 'bar, ...}])
```

Comment: This line : `cols = row + math.ceil((len(_i)%row)/row)` -> `row` is undefined.

Comment: @EricLavault thanks for pointing out. I fixed it then got the error i'd been encountering.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you add a figure to the existing figure instead of a trace. In other words, `chunk` must be a trace :

```
# DRAW A CUBE
chunk = go.Mesh3d(
    x=[0.0, 0.0, x, x, 0.0, 0.0, x, x],
    y=[0.0, y, y, 0.0, 0.0, y, y, 0.0],
    z=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, z, z, z, z],
    intensity=np.linspace(0, 1, 8, endpoint=True),
    intensitymode='cell',
    i=[7, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 6, 6, 4, 0, 3, 2],
    j=[3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 5, 2, 0, 1, 6, 3],
    k=[0, 7, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 1, 5, 5, 7, 6],
    showscale=False
)
# APPEND THE CUBE
fig.add_trace(chunk, row=r, col=c)
```